# MS SQL inner join to fill out same column names

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, inner-join, sql-server-2014

Hey all I have 2 tables that have the same data in them. Those tables are called **TrainingCity** and **TrainingState**.

I am updating the row in the **tEvents** table with the users inputted data on the website form. However, **tTRIP** table attaches to the *already entered* data on the **tEvents** table.

I am looking to grab just the **TrainingCity** and **TrainingState** values and *include them* in the update to the tEvents table of the same name columns.

```
SELECT 
    *, TT.TrainingCity, TT.TrainingState 
FROM 
    tEvents AS TE
INNER JOIN 
    tTRIP AS TT
ON 
    TT.RequestID = TE.RequestID
WHERE 
    TE.EventID = 12
AND 
    TE.RequestID = 801
```

My update query looks like this:

```
command = new SqlCommand("UPDATE " +
                            "tEvents " +
                         "SET " +
                             buildTblVal +
                         " WHERE " +
                             "EventID = @eventID " + 
                         "AND " +
                             "RequestID = @reqID", con);
```

What would the query need to be modified too in order to grab those 2 values from the **tTRIP** table and place them into the **tEvents** table?

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit regarding the table schemas you're dealing with?  Also, you state "tTRIP table attaches to the already entered data on the tEvents table." What causes that to happen?

Comment: You're dynamically constructing SQL, providing column names at run time. Do you have a bad conscience? Perhaps you should :-) Were you to use [QueryFirst](http://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=bbsimonbb.QueryFirst), which I wrote, this option would be removed, and you would be happier and live longer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I just got it :)

```
UPDATE 
    tEvents 
SET 
    TrainingState = tT.TrainingState, 
    TrainingCity = tT.TrainingCity,
    ....[other columns here]... 
FROM (
    SELECT 
        TrainingCity, TrainingState, RequestID  
    FROM 
        tTRIP
     ) AS tT
WHERE 
    tT.RequestID = tEvents.RequestID
AND 
    tEvents.EventID = 12
AND 
    tEvents.RequestID = 801
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you're looking for something like this:

```
UPDATE TEvents
SET TrainingState = trip.TrainingState,
    TrainingCity = trip.TrainingCity
FROM TEvents events
    JOIN TTrip trip
        ON events.RequestId = trip.RequestId
WHERE events.EventId = 1
```

Example fiddle here: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/aa863/3/0

Comment: This would not update the data to both tables would it? I would imagine that I would have to **SET TrainingState = "blah"** in order for **"blah"** to be set in **trip.TrainingState** as well, right? As your query looks like right now, it seems to only copy what's **currently** in the database on TrainingState for events.EventId = 1 and copies that over to trip.TrainingState?